# How does TomEE implement Dependency Injection?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, interface, dependency-injection, apache-tomee

I found this example, http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/injection-of-ejbs/README.html

And it claims to be an example of Dependency Injection.  I see multiple Interfaces an after those Interfaces are implemented, I don't see how the @EJB implementation is using anything DI.  It just looks like three different types using different Interfaces.

I expected to see one Interface and many different classes that implement it *and* are passed/injected to the DataReader class in the example, either by construction or setter.

How is this example showing Dependency Injection?

(am I supposed to post code from another website?)

This is the DataReader class:

```
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

/**
 * This is an EJB 3.1 style pojo stateless session bean
 * Every stateless session bean implementation must be annotated
 * using the annotation @Stateless
 * This EJB has 2 business interfaces: DataReaderRemote, a remote business
 * interface, and DataReaderLocal, a local business interface
 * <p/>
 * The instance variables 'dataStoreRemote' is annotated with the @EJB annotation:
 * this means that the application server, at runtime, will inject in this instance
 * variable a reference to the EJB DataStoreRemote
 * <p/>
 * The instance variables 'dataStoreLocal' is annotated with the @EJB annotation:
 * this means that the application server, at runtime, will inject in this instance
 * variable a reference to the EJB DataStoreLocal
 */
//START SNIPPET: code
@Stateless
public class DataReader {

    @EJB
    private DataStoreRemote dataStoreRemote;
    @EJB
    private DataStoreLocal dataStoreLocal;
    @EJB
    private DataStore dataStore;

    public String readDataFromLocalStore() {
        return "LOCAL:" + dataStoreLocal.getData();
    }

    public String readDataFromLocalBeanStore() {
        return "LOCALBEAN:" + dataStore.getData();
    }

    public String readDataFromRemoteStore() {
        return "REMOTE:" + dataStoreRemote.getData();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is DI just because you get injected an implementation without knowing which one it is. That's right that the example doesn't provide N implementations of the same interface to not make it too complicated, the goal is just to show how injections work.